# How to move Windows 10 Task bar icon back into a group

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

When I started out on my new Windows 10 installation, the task bar have an "extra menu" when pressed, reveals extra task bar items:

[image: Started]

Now one day when I started playing with the task bar items, I moved all the icons in the "extra menu" out, now there are basically a big row of items:

[image: Big row of items]

I want to move some of them back to the "extra" list so my taskbar is not crowded. I tried to drag one item on top of the other one, but it didn't do anything, just move back to where it belongs. What is the proper way to get the list back?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Right-click the Taskbar and choose *Settings*.
- Select *Taskbar* in the left column.
- Scroll down to *Notification area*.
- Click *Select which icons appear on the taskbar*
- Adjust as you'd like.

[image: Taskbar System notification tray settings screen Windows 10]